# enabling blank values into database

Tags: php, symfony

What is the proper way to make attribute accept null values. i browsed StackOverflow about this and found ouy about `Assert`. Here's how i'm using it

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=100)
     *  @Assert\Blank()  
     */
    private $title;
```

Unfortunatelly when i try to save record without the title i get:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Post (content, title, topic_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["sdf", null, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `nullable`:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)  
 */
private $title;
```

Then update your schema with `./app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#column

Comment: i willbe able to  do it in 4 minutes;)

Answer (score 1):

It will allow `NULL` values in the column:

```
ALTER TABLE Post MODIFY `title` VARCHAR(255) NULL;
```